# Gauge - Implementing step crashing VS 17

Tags: crash, getgauge

I had created a spec several days ago and needed to create a new one. Instead of creating a new step implementation I used the same one as the previous spec. And since a couple of the steps were similar to the first spec I copy pasted the steps and changed what I needed. Then made the changes in the spec file to match the implementation. After a clean and build I noticed the steps were red (needing to be implemented, so I clicked implement step, and selected the file, which crashed VS17. It restarted by itself and gave me an error which you see below. Deleting the step implementations it still crashes. Deleting the step and implementation and rewriting them both still causes the crash, but the implementation is still generated.

Windows 10 Pro
Visual Studio community 2017

System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)at Gauge.VisualStudio.Model.Project.GetGaugeImplementations(Project containingProject)at Gauge.VisualStudio.Model.Project.RefreshImplementations()at Gauge.VisualStudio.Model.Project.HasDuplicateImplementation(ITextSnapshotLine line)at Gauge.VisualStudio.Highlighting.UnimplementedStepTagger.<GetTags>d__4.MoveNext()at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Tagging.Implementation.TagAggregator`1.d__39.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)

Comment: As a work around. I undid all my progress and re-wrote everything. This time I did not copy paste steps or implementations, and let gauge generate the step implementations.

Comment: If you still have this issue, would it be possible to post a sample project that throws this error? The best place to report bugs is https://github.com/getgauge/gauge-visualstudio.